# Find the determinant of M

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Good evening.
There is a Matrix M $n\times n$, where $m_{ij} = a_{i}a_{j}$ when $i\neq j$ and 
$m_{ii} = a_{i}^2+k$.
Find the determinant of the M.

I have found that for $n=1$:
$$det(M_{1\times1})=k+a_1^2$$
for $n=2$:
$$det(M_{2\times 2})=k^2+k(a_1^2+a_2^2)$$
for $n=3$:
$$det(M_{3\times 3})=k^3+k^2(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)$$
As I understand for n=t will get
$$det(M_{t\times t})=k^t+k^{t-1}(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+...a_{t}^2)$$

After that I tried to use mathematical induction, but it didn't help me.
Thank you for help!

Comment: Observe that $M_{t\times t}=aa^T+kI$ for $a=(a_1,...,a_t)^T$ and use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) with $u=v=a$ and $A=kI$.